# Does the JProfiler10 support Tomcat9?

Tags: memory-leaks, jprofiler, tomcat9

Our project is deploying under the tomcat9. 
There is a potential memory leaking issue I'm investigating.
I have experience in Jprofiler8 to solve similar issues, but JP8 doesn't work on Tomcat9. 
I googled that perhaps Jp10 supports Tomcat9 although I don't find out the Tomcat9 option in server list.
Which version of Jprofiler supports Tomcat9?
Or could you please recommend me other good tools?

Thanks.

I use eclipse 4.6 to integrate with JProfiler 10.1.4, and startup server by eclipse with profile mode. The JProfile can be executed, but cannot connect to my Tomcat9 server.[Jprofiler Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvyBI.png)
The Eclipse console is [Eclipse Jprofiler argument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUvUx.png)

Comment: I solved this issue. Thank you @Ingo Kegel for your help, you helped me to filter out some potential reasons. Right now, I could monitor the local tomcat server by manual profile although I've done the integration with my IDE.

Comment: The steps: 1) Add -Xshareclasses:none -agentpath:{Your JProfiler installation path}\jprofilerti.dll=port=8849 into JVM arguments  2) start server, make sure there is "Jprofiler > " in the eclipse console window. 3) Run JProfiler with 8849 port. Emphasis, only simple model works well for me, if I choose the full functionalities one (sorry for forget the option), it still can't connect to Server. That's all. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, JProfiler 10 supports Tomcat 9. "Support" in this case is more relevant for the profiled JVM than for the particular servlet container.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using the JProfile V10.1.2. However, the Integration wizard hasn't option of Apache Tomcat 9.x, the Tomcat 8.x is the latest version it supports. And it is really hard to find the existing server deployed on local Tomcat 9. It's weird.

Comment: You can use the wizard for Tomcat 8.x. The wizards only add a VM parameter to the invocation in the start script. The "Generic" integration wizard gives you the VM parameter so that you can add it manually.

Comment: I tried manual connection, however, it doesn't work as well. Jprofiler shutdown my eclipse. I tried download latest version of JProfile, and integrated into eclipse. But the issue is still there. "Cannot connect to server". I checked log of eclipse console, the port is correct (in fact, because of the integration, I can't change anything). I've no idea....

Comment: Dear Ingo, you're the expert on Jprofiler. I updated the information of issue, could you please have a look it? It may be normal issue for you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does the stderr output of the Tomcat instance contain lines prefixed with "JProfiler>"? Do you have an internal firewall that prevents socket connections to Tomcat on arbitrary ports?

Comment: Does the "stderr output  of the Tomcat" mean the console? I checked the console and logs of Tomcat, there is no line contain "JProfiler>" except the "INFO: Command line argument: -Xshareclasses:none -agentpath:C:\PROGRA~1\JPROFI~1.4\bin\WINDOW~1\jprofilerti.dll=port=33533 -Djprofiler.64bit=true". This is the only place contains "JProfiler" word.

Comment: I turned off firewall for testing, the issue is still there.

Comment: If there is no `JProfiler>`in stderr, then the `-agentpath` parameter is not passed to the JVM.  Did you make the change manually to the start script or do you profile via the eclipse integration?